# C defines proper usage

Tags: c

A problem with C defines:

```
#define RANGE1_ms 64
#define FS 16000.0f
#define BS 64
#define COUNTER1_LIMIT ( ( RANGE1_ms/1000.0f)* FS/BS )
```

This gives `16.0` for `COUNTER1_LIMIT`.

Debugging the code in Eclipse shows all is OK. 
However, when I build release version from a makefile, it produces different result. I have narrowed the problem down to this line:

```
if( counter1 == (uint16_t)COUNTER1_LIMIT )
{
    ...
}
```

where `counter1` is `uint16_t`.

What am I doing wrong with those defines?

This solves the problem:

```
if( counter1 == 16 )
```

but that's not the way to go.

Comment: converting `float` to integers of any type may lead to loss of precision. The 16.0 might get converted to 15.999999 and while converting to uint16_t would get converted to 15.

Comment: I will suggest also promote counter1 to `float` and check if the absolute difference between them is less than say `0.001` .

Comment: Try #define COUNTER1_LIMIT ((uint16_t)( ( RANGE1_ms/1000.0f)* 16000.0f/ 64 ))

Comment: @SimoneCifani It is exactly the same, there is no difference in what you suggested and what he has written

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya You are right, don't care my stupid comment

Comment: Do you really need floating point here? Try `#define COUNTER1_LIMIT (RANGE1_ms * 16000 / (1000 * 64))`.

Comment: @n.m. For portability reasons, it is better to write that expression so that it doesn't overflow 65535. `int` could be 16 bits on some systems, meaning that your macro will yield undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid FP math with the pre-processor.

```
// Avoid the following
#define FS 16000.0f
#define COUNTER1_LIMIT ( ( RANGE1_ms/1000.0f)* FS/BS )
```

Alternative 1: use integer math that rounds quotients to nearest.  Adding half the divisor works when dividend/divisor are positive.

```
#define RANGE1_ms 64
#define FS 16000
#define BS 64
#define ms_PER_s 1000
#define COUNTER1_LIMIT_N (1ul * RANGE1_ms * FS)
#define COUNTER1_LIMIT_D (1ul * ms_PER_s * BS )
#define COUNTER1_LIMIT_I ((COUNTER1_LIMIT_N + COUNTER1_LIMIT_D/2)/COUNTER1_LIMIT_D)
#define COUNTER1_LIMIT_F (1.0*COUNTER1_LIMIT_N/COUNTER1_LIMIT_D)

if (counter1 == COUNTER1_LIMIT_I)
```

---

Alternative 2:

When constants like `FS` truly need to be FP like `16123.4f`, use a rounding function rather than truncation with an integer cast like `(uint16_t)`

```
#include <math.h>
if (counter1 == lround(COUNTER1_LIMIT))
```

---

Alternative 3:

When constants like `FS` truly need to be FP like `16123.4f`, add 0.5 then truncate with an integer cast like `(uint16_t)`.  The add 0.5 trick works when the value is positive.  It fails with a number of values when adding 0.5 is not exact.  Yet has the advantage: it can be computed, as in OP's case, at compile time.

```
if (counter1 == (uint16_t)(COUNTER1_LIMIT + 0.5))
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the bug is that floating point numbers are accurate, see the millions of others posts on SO about this, for example [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

But in your specific case the problem is that you use floating point where it isn't needed or useful. You just need a compile-time constant. Fix the expression like this:

```
#define RANGE1_ms 64u
#define COUNTER1_LIMIT (16000u / 64u * RANGE1_ms / 1000u )
```

Comment: This "works" when `16000u / 64u` is exact - like here.  It can introduce unneeded computational error of `COUNTER1_LIMIT` with `FS / 64u` and `FS` is not a multiple of 64.

Comment: @chux None of that is mentioned or made clear by the question. This part is the only thing making this question worth preserving though. If the question is just yet another "why are my float  numbers inaccurate" question, then it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are susceptible to loss of precision. The `16.0` can get converted to `15.9999` when loaded as a temporary. Casting it to `uint16_t` makes it `15` that doesn't compare against `16`.

You need a function to round the floating point values. That you can call on `COUNTER1_LIMIT`.

Other option would be to promote `counter1` to `float` and check if the absolute difference between this and `COUNTER1_LIMIT` is less than a small value like `0.001`.

It can be done as

```
float diff = counter1 - COUNTER1_LIMIT;
if(diff > -0.001 && diff < 0.001) { 
    ...
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: It's a hack, but will consider it.

Comment: Use this technique is float values are an absolute requirement. Like say `COUNTER_LIMIT1` can be `16.5`. If it is known to be an integer value, use what @Lundin has suggested.

Comment: @Danijel It's not a hack, it is how you compare float numbers for equality, you introduce a "delta" which is the desired value +/- a certain interval. This does however require a run-time check, which shouldn't be needed here.

Answer (score 1):

`RANGE1_ms/1000.0f` is `64/1000.0f` . The problem is, computers cannot represent 0.064 exactly.  Ultimately, numbers are represented as a*2<sup>b</sup>, where a and b are integers, which is impossible for 0.064 . So, `RANGE1_ms/1000.0f` is *approximately* 0.064. When you multiply it by 16000f and divide by 64, you receive *approximately* 16f.  It may be 15.999999, or 16.000003, or something. When you cast it to `uint16_t`, it becomes either 15 or 16.

One way is to cast it as `(uint16_t)(COUNTER1_LIMIT+0.5)`.  It will round it to the closest integer.  Alternatively, if your COUNTER1_LIMIT is always integer (that is you know that the expression should produce integer number), you may do

```
#define FS_BY_1000 16
#define COUNTER1_LIMIT (RANGE1_ms * FS_BY_1000/BS)
```

Comment: `+0.5` solution seems nice.